# Separar cadena y almacenar valores en array

Tags: php, regex, split, scraping, explode

Estoy raspando una web y he obtenido algunos datos que no logro ordenar.

### Lo que tengo hecho:

```
    <?php

    require 'simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('https://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Helmet');

// NPC Donde Comprar
function dondeComprar(){
    global $html;
        foreach($html->find('div#item-trades-buyfrom td') as $val_buy){
            $patronBorrarAsteriscos = '/[*]/';
            $reemplazoAsteriscos = '';
            $cadenaConAsteriscos = $val_buy->plaintext;
            $cadenaSinAsteriscos = preg_replace($patronBorrarAsteriscos, $reemplazoAsteriscos, 
            $cadenaConAsteriscos).',';

            echo $cadenaSinAsteriscos;
        }
    }


    ?>
```

### El resultado que genera:

```
Flint,Rathleton,390,Kroox,Kazordoon,390,Sam,Thais,390,
```

### Lo que necesito hacer:

1. Separar los datos donde están las comas (;)
2. Ordenar los datos en un array
3. Acceder fácilmente a esos datos

Lo que espero es acceder a cada grupo de datos mediante sus índices. Quiero poder imprimir por pantalla cada grupo de datos individualmente con el formato:

```
NOMBRE   | CIUDAD    | VALOR
$name[0] | $city[0]  | $value[0]
$name[1] | $city[1]  | $value[1]
$name[2] | $city[2]  | $value[2]
$name[3] | $city[3]  | $value[3]
$name[4] | $city[4]  | $value[4]
 n...[n] |  n...[n]  |  n... [n]
```

De momento eso es todo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xerif** gracias por tu aporte, lo usé pero el resultado no era lo que yo esperaba para mi caso (creo que no supe trabajarlo en realidad).

Volviendo a analizar lo que necesito he descubierto que el modo de almacenar datos en arrays como yo sugería no es el más adecuado para mis necesidades (o es mas complicado para mi entender), eso se debe a que `$html` es de por sí un array y sólo debo acceder a él por medio del índice... sin más.

Entonces considerando que mis datos originales vienen en formato `Nombre, Ciudad, Valor, Nombre, Ciudad, Valor, Nombre, Ciudad, Valor, ...` descubrí que el `nombre` corresponde a múltiplos de 3 e iteré de 3 en 3 con un **blucle for** contando desde `$i = 0;`, así obtuve sólo los `$i` correspondientes al `nombre`. En el caso de la `ciudad` hago lo mismo pero contando desde posición `$i = 1;` y finalmente para los datos del `valor` de nuevo hice lo mismo pero desde posición `$i=2;`... todos con incrementos de 3 en 3 `$i+=3;`.

Aquí está mi código por si alguien más lo necesita:

```
    <?php
    require 'simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('https://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Helmet');

    // NPC Donde Comprar
       function dondeComprar(){

        global $html;
        $data = $html->find('div#item-trades-buyfrom td'); // Esto es un array

        $contador = count($data);

        // Muestra los nombres
        for ($i=0; $i < $contador; $i+=3) { 
            echo $Npc = $data[$i]->plaintext.'<br>';
        }
            echo '<br><br>';

        // Muestra las ciudades
        for ($i=1; $i < $contador; $i+=3) { 
            echo $Ciudad = $data[$i]->plaintext.'<br>';
        }
        echo '<br><br>';

        // Muestra el valor
        for ($i=2; $i < $contador; $i+=3) { 
            echo $Valor = $data[$i]->plaintext.'<br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Y obtengo como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Nombre:
Aldo
Azil
Baltim
Brengus
Cedrik

Ciudades:
Venore
Darashia
Svargrond
Port Hope
Liberty Bay

Valor:
12
12
12
12
12
```

Con ese resultado así obtenido podré agregar los datos a una tabla, con lo cual obtendré el orden que necesito (es lo que haré ahora).

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer un `explode()` y luego partir el array en trozos con `array_chunk()`.

Ejemplo

```
 $data = 'Flint,Rathleton,390,Kroox,Kazordoon,390,Sam,Thais,390';
 $array = array_chunk(explode(',', $data), 3);
 print_r($array);
```

Resultado

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Flint
        [1] => Rathleton
        [2] => 390
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Kroox
        [1] => Kazordoon
        [2] => 390
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sam
        [1] => Thais
        [2] => 390
    )
)
```